# How to lsearch for last matching regular expression in list

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm trying to find a way to find the first and  last matching word or regular expression in a list.

Something like:

```
set list "The dog rant to the field by the red house..."

set first [lsearch -regexp $list \[Tt\]he] 
($first =0)
set last [lsearch -last -regexp $list \[Tt\]he
($last=7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set res [lsearch -nocase -all $list the]
set first [lindex $res 0]
set last [lindex $res end]
```

Unless you want to specifically exclude uppercase h or e (or look for word boundaries), this one is equivalent and about four times faster.

Comment: Peter, I used "the", but I need the regexp for my real world example.  That said, your examples logic works perfectly for me!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since regular expressions can be quite slow, it is best to execute the regular expression only once rather than searching the target line multiple times.

```
   set list "The dog rant to the field by the red house..."
   set matches [regexp -inline -all {[Tt]he} $list]
   set first [lindex $matches 0]
   set last [lindex $matches end]
```

If you need the indexes into $list where the matches are located, use the
`-indices` option.

```
  set matches [regexp -indices -inline -all {[Tt]he} $list]
```

References: [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the length of the real data and the distribution of matches, it might be easiest to do the search on the reversed list and convert:

```
set ridx [lsearch -regexp [lreverse $list] {[Tt]he}]
set last [expr {[llength $list] - 1 - $ridx}]
```

Comment: I didn't realize there was an lreverse function!  That will definitely come in handy!  Thank you